# How to set up a reinforcement learning problem on a graph?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to deep RL and trying to to set up the problem (define the environment, actions, etc) and choose the appropriate algorithm.
I have a weighted, directed graph represented as an adjacency matrix:

```
G = [
    [0.3, 1.5, 0, 0.9],
    [20.1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 7.0, 9.0, 0],
    [0.9, 1.7, 10.2, 0]
]
```

I want my agent to iterate through the nodes, and its `states` will include the `in-connections` and `out-connections` per node. The `actions` should be a real value `(-inf, inf)` per `state`.

From a RL perspective, what is an algorithm that can solve this and how do I set up the state and actions to feed into a neural network? (one issue is that some nodes might have more edges and NN are usually fixed input size). The rewards per `state, action` pair are known.

Comment: You can look into graph neural networks. Some GNN architectures basically work on graphs with variable nodes/edges.